# How should the JavaDoc for Class and Main method differ?

Tags: java, class, methods, javadoc

Simple example:

Suppose I have a class that contains a `minValue` method, a `maxValue` method, and an `averageValue` method which each take a double array, and also the Main method.

Suppose also in the main method, I define a double array then print the its min, max and average values using the above methods.

What should Javadoc for the Class and Main method be?

I am quite new to Java and I always find the main method Javadoc just reiterates the class Javadoc and it seems pointless stating it.

E.g.

```
/**This class can be used to find the min, max and average value of an array

Main method: calculates the min, max and average value of an array*/
```

Is this correct, or is there a better way to differentiate Class and Main method Javadoc?

Comment: I personally wouldn't document the `main` method. Javadocs are for clients that will use the class. Is there even a point in documenting a class that looks like a self-contained exercise program?

Comment: You should document `main()` like any other *method:* give the information that shows what it does and how to call it. Bearing in mind that the caller is a human with a command line, not another pice of code.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't add a java doc for the `main` method

Also aside from a small description you should add the parameters and return type for each method in this format
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javadocs.html#add-new-comment

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Is this correct, or is there a better way to differentiate Class and Main method Javadoc?*

There is no correct or incorrect way, just recommendations.
Typically the *main method* should contain a minimal amount of code.

My recommendation would be to place your current code within a separate method, and call it from *main*.

Documenting this *method* might be easier to manage.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Example example = new Example();
    example.abc();
}

void abc() {

}
```